# python flask import error

Tags: python, flask, importerror

I am running the following code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

and getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/pi/programs/flask.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name Flask
```

I have tried installing flask through various methods , but still the problem persists

also, is there any alternative to flask???

Comment: Install it with `pip install Flask`. What operating system are you running?

Comment: We will need more information about how you attempted to install flask. What, exactly are these "various methods" you attempted? What is your OS? etc.

Comment: Is /home/pi/programs in either your pythonpath or your current working directory? Check it with echo "$PYTHONPATH"

Comment: i am using debian wheezy on a raspberry pi

Comment: these are the methods that i used

method 1
    `sudo apt-get install python-pip`
    `sudo pip install flask`

method 2
    `sudo easy_install virtualenv`
    `mkdir myproject`
    `cd myproject`
    `virtualenv venv`
    `.venv/bin/activate`
    `pip install Flask`

Comment: So you've thrown virtualenv into it now?

Comment: @MarkHildreth i even downloaded the package from flask website extracted it and run the setup , none of the methods seemed to have solved my problem

Comment: @JonClements [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/an-introduction-to-pythons-flask-framework/) is what i followed

Comment: I had this error too. Beware not to name file as `flask.py`!

Comment: ta zigomir, that was it for me. was pulling my hair out !

Comment: also don´t name your file `socket.py` !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just run `apt-get install python3-flask`

Edited to install the python3 version, since nobody should be using python2 now.

Comment: what ip should give in `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)`
i am getting the following error
**
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
  
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 613, in run_simple
    test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
**

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is fine, it will listen to all the interfaces. The port is not okay since you need to be root to use that. For testing usually people use 8080.

Comment: run "apt-get install python3-flask" if you are running python v3

Answer (score 180):

I ran into this error because I named the **test file** as **flask.py** and tried to run it! It creates **namespace conflict** with the **real flask module**!

**Delete** the **local test file** that you named **flask.py** and the respective **flask.pyc**. Give some other name! This will happen with other modules like `socket` etc where you are likely to give the same name for the test file as the standard module :-)

Comment: sqlalchemy, users also bump into the same issue. they name it as sqlalchemy.py :)

Comment: 2017... And this reply is still useful. Thank you and shame on my and on the filename I've chosen!

Comment: You'd think after programming in a language for years you would not forget this simple little gem.  I think this is the third time I landed on this page over the years.  Thanks again!

Comment: For me, it was because I had named a Python package as flask

Comment: As you point out, happens with socket too.  lolz

Answer (score 26):

The reason is your python file name is flask.

Comment: Could you provided more information to solving the problem?

Comment: Yikes! that was my problem too

Answer (score 11):

Just rename **flask.py** file also delete **flask.pyc** file

Answer (score 5):

**It's because of the name flask.py. It will import itself if the name is flask.py. Change the name and try again.**

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the name "flask.py" is problematic and what it should be changed to?

Comment: @vealkind its because the file will try to import the itself. Write some print statement in flask.py and then import flask in the same file and it will print the same thing twice, so..

Answer (score 1):

Restart virtual environment

```
$ virtualenv flask
```

Into dir flask run

```
$source ./bin/activate
```

Install python module again

```
$pip install "module"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Apparently you **can't** name your file **socket.py** either.

Answer (score 0):

exactly when we create file name as flask.py and then execute it for the first time it will execute and at the same time framework creates another file called flask.pyc .Now stop the process and start it again it will throw this error as instead of looking to actual framework flask file it is looking in to the one you created . To solve this problem 
Go to the folder you created flask.py and delete flask.pyc and then rename flask.py to some test_1.py ..save it and execute it . You should see no errors .

Answer (score 0):

Add `PYTHONPATH` to your environment:
`export PYTHONPATH=/root/environments/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`